# How to Show div in an iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

Kindly how to show a form in an iframe when a user clicks on register link.When a user on example1.com clicks on register,the form of example2.com should be shown in an iframe. I don't want to show the header menu+sidebar+footer of example2.com.Just want to show its form which in .

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think `<iframe src="//example2.com/form.html` will do

Comment: for that you have to create page which contains only form on example2.com

Comment: What Er.KT saying is absolute answer. Example1 also can be a separate html.

Comment: The right thing to do is to link to the other site's form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep example1 in a separate iframe. while clicking register, give the link to example2.

For this you have to design a 3 html file.

> 1.Main holder
>
> 2.example1.html for iframe in main holder
>
> 3.example2.html for onclick register action

Visit this site for your preference. [Click here](http://www.rcubesolutions.com/postget/register.html)